# Replace NAs by condition

Tags: r

```
ab<- as.factor(c("A","B","A","C","B","C","C"))
a123<- as.factor(c(NA,NA,NA,465,NA,532,456))
dd<- as.data.frame(cbind(ab,a123))
```

this is the data frame which i have, i want to replace NA values with 0 if value of column ab is A else NA = 1.

I have tried following code:

```
dd$Amount[is.Na(dd$Amount)]<- ifelse(my_dd$Activity=="Beneficiary Added", 0,1)
```

i get following error:

```
> dd$Amount[is.Na(dd$Amount)]<- ifelse(my_dd$Activity=="Beneficiary Added", 0, 1)
Error in `*tmp*`$Amount : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Comment: Just do `df <- data.frame(abc, a123)` as your method `as.data.frame(cbind` creates both `factor` columns

Comment: If you **do not** use `as.factor` when creating df this code `df$a123[is.na(df$a123)] <- ifelse(df[is.na(df$a123), 'abc']=="A", 0,1)` works nicely with your `df`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comment as an answer plus an example with `data.table` (much clearer syntax in my opinion):

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(abc = c("A","B","A","C","B","C","C"), a123 = c(NA,NA,NA,465,NA,532,456))
dt <- data.table(df)

# "Classic" data.frame syntax
df$a123[is.na(df$a123)] <- ifelse(df[is.na(df$a123), 'abc'] == "A", 0, 1)
# data.table one
dt[is.na(a123), a123 := ifelse(abc == "A", 0, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my suggestion.

```
abc<- c("A","B","A","C","B","C","C")
df<- data.frame(cbind(abc,a123),stringsAsFactors =FALSE)
df$your_var=ifelse(df$abc %in% "A" & df$a123 %in% NA, 0, ifelse(df$a123 %in% NA,1,df$a123)
print(df)
```

Best

Pavlo

Comment: @GirishKhole, don't you think this answer is a bit overcomplicated?

Comment: You are wellcome. Actually it is matter of taste. In my solution you use combination of "ifelse" and subsetting.